# isset function does not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

below i inserted my two forms

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<h2>working time</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<button name="starttime" class="starttime">starttime</button>
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
echo $name;
if(isset($_POST["starttime"])){
$date = date('Y-m-d');
require "database.php";
$sql = "SELECT name, ddate FROM karthick.date WHERE name = '$name' AND ddate = '$date'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $n = $row["name"];
        $d = $row["ddate"];
    }
}
if($n == $name && $d == $date){
    echo'<script>
    alert("Time already registered");
    </script>';
}else{
    header("location:http://localhost/karthick/attendance/datedata.php");
    exit;
}
}
?>
</form>
<form action = "datedata.php" method="post">
<button name="endtime" class="endtime">Endtime</button>
</form>
<form action="user.php" method="post">
<button name= "logout" class="logout">Logout</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

in the above form when the starttime is clicked it fetch the date and it check it with database if the date is already registered or not.if the date is not already registered it moves to next formthat i gave it in the header:link.

secode form

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
echo $name;
if(isset($_POST["starttime"]))
{
    $date_clicked = date('H:i:s');
    echo $date_clicked;
    $date_clicked1 = date('Y-m-d');
    echo $date_clicked1;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO karthick.date (name, ddate, starttime) VALUES ('$name', '$date_clicked1', '$date_clicked')";
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "inserted";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
}elseif(isset($_POST['endtime']))
{
    $date_clicked = date('H:i:s');
    $date_clicked1 = date('Y-m-d');
    $sql = "UPDATE karthick.date SET endtime='$date_clicked' WHERE name = '$name' AND ddate = '$date_clicked1'";
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "inserted";
    }else{
        echo "error";
        echo $name;
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

so the problem i am facing is when it moves to second form it only fetch the name and it doesn't fetch the date and time. so please help me.

Comment: try adding echo statement after this line `if(isset($_POST["starttime"]))` to check if it goes to that condition

Comment: i echoed the isset function in second form and it doesn't work

Comment: do `die(var_dump($_POST))` as the first line to check if the fields are indeed set.

Comment: Then it doesn't go to that condition.

Comment: Try also to remove the exit after the header function.

Comment: when the start time is pressed it checked the isset function in first form only when it directed to second form it doesn't checks the isset function that why it doesn't fetch the date and time @claudios

Comment: why not use only one submit button then check if user is registered an if not do another condition without going to another form.

Answer (score 1):

Your button has no value assigned, this will skip it on `$_POST` request:

```
<button name="starttime" class="starttime" value="insert value here">starttime</button>
```

Also you are missing the destination of your form `action=""` (it will default to the origin page, but it's better to declare it).

Then, when you change to the second form via the header statement

```php
 header("location:http://localhost/karthick/attendance/datedata.php");
```

It's not a `$_POST` request anymore, you would have load this via `ajax` and add post values, or pass them otherwise. The `$_SESSION` variables stay anyway, of course.